# How to compute Hours and Minutes in PHP with value of whole number and decimal

Tags: php

how to compute the total hours and minutes if i have for

ex. 3.56 to 2.43 hrs/mins

i already calculated manually this example and

i want to compute this if the decimal number is greater than 60 mins. will add to hours and if < mins  will remain as mins.

Comment: `3.56 to 2.43 hrs/mins` -- what does it mean?

Comment: im already calculated total hours and mins 3.56 is 3 hrs and 56 mins and 2 hrs 43 mins I want to add 56 & 43 if >60 add to 3 & 2 then excess remain to mins..

Comment: So you don't know how to add numbers? It's `+` then.

Comment: sir @zerkms, I want to add decimal separated from whole numbers and if the total mins is 60 or greater than 60 i will add 1 hour to whole number

Comment: right. And do you have any **particular** programming question?

Comment: i want to calculate the total hours and mins late http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/edbdd/2

Comment: yep, you want it. And what stops you from doing that? Any particular problem or you cannot program at all?

Comment: it round of the sum when using the +  ex. if 3.56+2.43=5.99

Comment: it should be like this 3.56 + 2.43 = 6.39hrs /mins

Comment: it should be. And what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Friday after-noon code :-)

```
function sumTime($a,$b)
{
    $ah=explode('.',$a);
    $bh=explode('.',$b);

    $hours=$ah[0]+$bh[0];
    $minutes=$ah[1]+$bh[1];

    if($minutes <60){
    $done= $hours.'.'.$minutes;
    }else{
    $x= $minutes%60;
    $done=($hours+1) .'.'.$x;
    }
    return $done;

}

echo sumTime('3.56','2.43');
```

Comment: Thanks @Dagon, what if you have multiple row values?

Comment: parse the function an array, then use some loops on that array the principles the same. jsut watc the division, it wont be +1 by default